# For the graph of a rose ($r=\cos k\theta$), why d0es are there 2k petals for even values of k while only k petals for odd values of k?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

For the graph of the polar rose ($r=\cos k\theta$), why is it that there 2k petals for even k values while there are only k petals when k is odd? From playing around on Desmos, I understand that when k is odd, the graph overlaps itself after 180 degrees but why is this the case? Why does the graph not also overlap itself when k is even? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe helps http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626592/prove-that-the-rose-in-the-polar-plane-has-2n-petals-when-n-is-even/626622#626622

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)):

> When $k$ is even, the entire graph of the rose will be traced out exactly once when the value of $\theta$ changes from $0$ to $2\pi$. When $k$ is odd, this will happen on the interval between $0$ and $\pi$. (More generally, this will happen on any interval of length $2\pi$ for $k$ even, and $\pi$ for $k$ odd.)

I also request you to see [here](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa2013/Thurston/Write-Ups/Write-up%2011/Polar_Petals.html). Hope it helps.